# Chrome Adaware candy-box.biz

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, adware

My Chrome, version 36 in win7, keeps randomly spawn tabs with address  `http://www.candy-box.biz/adv/index.php?url=.....`. 
I can't remove this adware/malware, I try:

- look for souspicious extentions
- look for souspicious tasks in the chrome task manager
- use the [Junkware Removal Tools](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/junkware-removal-tool/)
- EDIT use the adware cleaner
- launch spybot
- clean the cache.

but none of this solution resolved the problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: In case you haven't already, try scanning your system using [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/).

Comment: even the adware cleaner is not enough

Comment: Did it find anything? Are other browser affected?

Comment: AdwCleaner did find some chrome extentions and I removed them. If I run it now it just find extension `Found [Extension] : cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo` , so apparently this extention has not be removed. I never use IE but when I start it now there is a warning: "An external programs wants to change the defaul search engine"

Answer (score 1):

I finnally found the source of the problem:

It was The `CandyBox3` program. I could find it in the Installed Program list. Unistall it is not enough 
(actually the unistall program does not remove anything). I had to stop the procress `cab.exe` and `aus.exe` using [Process Explorer](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fit-it%2Fsysinternals%2Fbb896653.aspx&ei=gpMRVOquDqOQ7AbkqIGICg&usg=AFQjCNGCizDF7JafJiaZU1kWtEjB_Y1wUA&sig2=tTCyVDweMOlteBNepTpCcQ&bvm=bv.74894050,d.ZGU) and removing manually the directory`C:\Program Files (x86)\CandyBox3.0` .